# AWS ElasticBeanstalk running NodeJS - How to get the Authorization header to come through?

Tags: authorization, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS ElasticBeanstalk application running a NodeJS server.

I would like to lock down the api, so that only users that have been authenticated by Cognito can access the various server-side methods.

I have set up the authentication with Cognito on the client-side which gets hold of the access token JWT.

I should just be able to pass this JWT to the server via the Authorization http header (or a custom header, I don't mind) and authenticate the user on the server-side before allowing them access to resources.

However, it seems that AWS ElasticBeanstalk doesn't allow the Authorization header, or any custom headers, through for some reason.

I'm not sure why it wouldn't allow these headers through. I could put the JWT in a property in the request body, rather than the header, but this shouldn't be necessary and doesn't make sense for GET requests.

Could someone let me know how to configure EB to allow the Authorization or any custom HTTP header through?

I didn't want to have to put API gateway in front of my API if I can help it, and thought this would be simple to implement. If there are any other authentication / authorization architectures that are possible, I'd be happy to hear about them as well.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Joe,
did you find the solution how to let the Authorization header go through?